# problems with ellipse TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-shape

I'm working on a mac, I use the package TikZ and it works.
But I have problems when I want use ellipse or diamond ex :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ellipse] {Ellipse};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If somebody could help me thank you !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` as the shape `ellipse` is defined by it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ellipse,draw] {Ellipse};       %% draw just to show the shape

\node[diamond,draw] at (0,-3) {Diamond};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun as usual.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(8,8)
    \rput(2,6){\ovalnode{A}{PSTricks}}
    \rput(6,2){\dianode{B}{TikZ}}
    \ncline{<-}{A}{B}\nbput[nrot=:U]{inheritance direction}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]